# Why can't I replace this function with a lambda

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda

I'm writing a RNN in tensorflow and I want to stack a few LSTM cells on top of each other. According to the tensorflow tutorial I should do it like so:

```
    def lstm_cell():
        return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
    stacked_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
        [lstm_cell() for _ in range(number_of_layers)])
```

When I do this, things work as expected. But I wondered if I could replace the defining of the function with a simple lambda function...unfortunately that doesn't work. What I replaced the above code with was:

```
    stacked_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lambda:tf.contrib.rnn.
        BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size) for _ in range(number_of_layers)])
```

I thought this would work since my understanding of the "lambda" in python was specifically so that I could replace having to define a separate function for very simple functions like this. Is my understanding of lambda wrong? The error message I get when doing the bottom one is:

```
    AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'zero_state'
```

I would have thought that the two different methods of stacking LSTMs was equivalent, but apparently not?

Comment: You're not calling the lambda function (and also the lambda is pointless - you could just call `BasicLSTMCell` directly).

Comment: You confused defining a function, and inlining what the function *does*. `lstm_cell()` executes what the function does, it doesn't define a function. Replace `lstm_cell()` with what the `lstm_cell` function body does, not with a new function definition.

Comment: You guys are right, I forgot to actually call the lambda function. I added parenthesis () and it worked. Also, I tried removing the lambda altogether and it works as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[lambda:tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size) for _ in range(number_of_layers)]
```

Here, `lambda:tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)` *only defines a function and does not call it*. Instead, you can directly access `BasicLSTMCell()` function:

```
[tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size) for _ in range(number_of_layers)]
```

You can then further shorten it by having `MultiRNNCell` and `BasicLSTMCell` imported this way:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import MultiRNNCell, BasicLSTMCell

lstm_stacks = [BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size) for _ in range(number_of_layers)]
stacked_lstm = MultiRNNCell(lstm_stacks)
```